# //@ts-check stops working in the current version of vscode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

VSCode has a feature where you can typecheck regular javascript files with the //@ts-check comment. However, this feature has recently stopped working for me and I have no idea why. I do not have a tsconfig.json or a jsconfig.json set, though according to the documentation neither should be required. I am running the latest version of VSCode, and the tsc installed is v 2.4, which should support this feature.

[image: ts-check]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had javascript.validate.enable = false

That setting needs to be true.